# mobx contenful simple api call

Tags: mobx, contentful

I have a basic react app (CRA) with mobx and I simply would like to get all the entries of a contentful space.

with a simple store I can see my entries in the react console but I can't find a way to display it in my component.

```
class ProjetsStore {

@observable projets = {}

@action fetchAll(){
window.fetch(`${API_BASE_URL}/spaces/${API_SPACE_ID}/entries?
access_token=${API_KEY}&content_type=projet`)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(prj => this.projets = prj)
```

The component is quite basic actually but whatever I try, I can't find a way to simply display anything even if everything is present in this.props.projetsStore in react tool.

```
@inject(['projetsStore'])
@observer

class Projets extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
  this.props.projetsStore.fetchAll()
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
       ...
    </div>
)
}
}
```

If someone can point me to some direction or ressource to simply fetch data from an api with mobx and make it dispo as props via provider, that would be awesome.

Thanks.

Comment: What does the `prj` data look like? Your `projets` is a regular object, and MobX can't pick up keys that are added dynamically. You need a [**map**](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/map.html) for that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with mobx and I'm not sure how you how the store works but I believe you have to set the data on the component itself, or?

```
@inject(['projetsStore'])
@observer

class Projets extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
  this.props.projetsStore.fetchAll()
    .then(data => this.setState({data})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your top level component with a `<Provider>` from `mobx-react` package.

```
<Provider projetsStore={projetsStore}>
    <Projets />
</Provider>
```

Then inject using a string, not array.

```
@inject('projetsStore')
@observer
class Projets extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.projetsStore.fetchAll()
  }
```